# Spring Boot with spring-boot-starter-web fails to compile in maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using jdk1.7 and spring boot 1.4.2.Release.I created a brand new Spring boot project from start.spring.io. It compiled fine. I tried to add the below dependency for exposing a REST web service.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I get the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to 
collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-
web:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE -> org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-
validator:jar:5.2.4.Final: Could not transfer artifact 
org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.2 from/to spring-ext 
(http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/): repo.spring.io: Unknown host 
repo.spring.io -> [Help 1]
```

It takes the http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local link which does not have jboss related files.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi,  it seems you don't have connection to maven repository to download the dependencies. Could you check your connection from IDE?

Comment: I am running in a corporate domain. I was able to download the other jars from the local domain. And I can see the shrinkwrap-bom pom.xml in my domain. But, it seems to be fetching it from repo.spring.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Your pom should look like this`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

after that you need to run it with command `mvn spring-boot:run` from the project directory

I hope this time it will defenetly work only need to copy and pase this pom content to your pom file

To build spring boot application from scratch you can follow the [link](http://www.jhaji.in/2016/02/how-to-start-with-boot-scratch-step-1.html)

Comment: It still failed with the same error. My current pom contains <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: can you share your pom file

Comment: I was able to run it from command line fine. Does this not work from IntelliJ with target as maven clean install. I also had a Run configuration within IntelliJ that says spring-boot:run in Command Line. Does that not work?

Comment: @SwatiGupta verify if you configured a different Maven installation for IntelliJ compared to the one you use on the command line. My guess is that you're using different Maven installations in IntelliJ/command line with different configurations. One of your configurations probably has `repo.spring.io` configured as a central repository while the other doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, just adding the *repository* configuration to the pom.xml didn't work. I had to add the following code into */maven-installation-dir/conf/settings.xml* file.

```
<mirror>
    <id>central-proxy</id>
    <name>central-proxy</name>
    <url>http://corporate-intranet/repo/url</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf></mirror>
```

I hope it helps someone.